# Javascript: Get all dates between from and to dates

Tags: javascript

I am using the following in a ReactJS app:

```
var getDaysArray = function(s, e) {
  for (var a = [], d = new Date(s); d <= e; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
    a.push(new Date(d));
  }
  return a;
};

const abc = new Date(item.DateTo.toDate()).toISOString().substring(0, 10);
const def = new Date(item.DateFrom.toDate()).toISOString().substring(0, 10);

var daylist = getDaysArray(def, abc);
```

The DateTo and DateFrom are stored as a firebase timestamp - so am converting this and both abc and def return correct (in console.log) = 2022-05-25 and 2022-05-31 so wondering why this is not working?

daylist always returns an empty array []

Comment: You need to double-check whether you're wrapping stuff with `new Date`. You're doing it with things that are already dates in multiple places, and you aren't doing it with `e` before comparing it to `d` for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here came from the fact you were transforming your dates into
`String` using the following command : `new Date(item.DateTo.toDate()).toISOString().substring(0, 10);`

Then you were comparing a string and a date object in your for loop with `d <= e`

To work with date in JS, you should let them as date as much as possible

```js
const item = {
  DateTo: 1653462937961,
  DateFrom: 1652997600000,
}

const getDaysArray = function(s, e) {
  const a = []
  for (let d = new Date(s); d <= e; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
    a.push(new Date(d));
  }
  return a;
};

const abc = new Date(item.DateTo)
const def = new Date(item.DateFrom)

var daylist = getDaysArray(def, abc);
console.log(daylist)
```

Note : Try to avoid use `var` and rather use `const`

and as @Louys Patrice Bessette mentioned, you should use meaningful variable names.

For example use `startDate` instead of `s` or even `dates` instead of `a`

Comment: And please use meaningful variable names.

Comment: Yes ofc but i dind't want to completely change the variable names from the example

Comment: Will use variable names that make sense! FYI, I changed the const to const abc = new Date(item.DateTo.toDate()) and const def = new Date(item.DateFrom.toDate()) - using Firebase timestamps

Comment: @RenaudC5  ;) that was an advise to OP.